# Erlang shared queue/shared counter with blocking(Concurrency, message passing)

Tags: erlang

I have multiple threads that need to access a shared list of numbers. The list should be updated before the next thread requests a new number. Therefore I really liked the following example that used the blocking mailbox queue. I can be sure that successive threads are getting a new and unique number in the order that they are requested.

The following example came from [this site](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1454463)

```
sequence1.erl (raw implementation)
-module(sequence1).
-export([make_sequence/0, get_next/1, reset/1]).

% Create a new shared counter.
make_sequence() ->
  spawn(fun() -> sequence_loop(0) end).
sequence_loop(N) ->
  receive
  {From, get_next} ->
        From ! {self(), N},
        sequence_loop(N + 1);
  reset ->
        sequence_loop(0)
  end.
% Retrieve counter and increment.
get_next(Sequence) ->
  Sequence ! {self(), get_next},
  receive
        {Sequence, N} -> N
  end.
% Re-initialize counter to zero.
reset(Sequence) ->
Sequence ! reset.
```

I altered the counter functions to work for my own project. My accumulator-Processes know when to stop taking numbers from the list/Counter because of a guard in the accum/5 function. Each accumulator-Process takes exactly T/P numbers before returning.

```
-module(pi).
-export([main/0, child/0, get_next/1, sequence_loop/1]).

%main/0
main() ->
T = 1000000,        %io:fread("Terms? ","~d"),
P = 4,              %io:fread("Processes? ","~d"),
pi(T,P).

 %  Code executed by the parent process.
pi(T, P) -> 
    Pid0 = spawn(pi, sequence_loop, [1]),
    Pid1 = spawn(pi, child, []),
    Pid2 = spawn(pi, child, []),
    Pid3 = spawn(pi, child, []),
    Pid4 = spawn(pi, child, []),

    Pid0 ! {start, 1},

   Tpart = 250000,          %Tpart = T div P,
   Width = 1.0 / T,
   Pid1 ! {work, self(), T, Tpart, Width, Pid0},
   Pid2 ! {work, self(), T, Tpart, Width, Pid0},
   Pid3 ! {work, self(), T, Tpart, Width, Pid0},
   Pid4 ! {work, self(), T, Tpart, Width, Pid0},
    await([Pid1, Pid2,Pid3, Pid4], 0.0).

%  Parent awaits replies from the child processes.
await([], Final) -> io:format(" Final Sum: ~.8f \n", [(Final * 4.0)]);
await([Pid | Rest], Final) ->
    receive
        {done, Pid, Sum} ->
        Partial = Final + Sum,
        await(Rest, Partial)
    end.

%  Code executed by the child processes. In pi, child calls the accum function which returns a partial sum. 
% Once the sum has been returned, child sends a done message to the parent which includes the partial sum from accum. The following code will compile and run.

child() ->
    receive
        {work, Parent, T, Tpart, Width, Pid0} ->
            Partial = accum(T, Tpart, Width, Pid0, 0, 1),
            Parent ! {done, self(), Partial}
    end.


    %calculate the area of rectangles. 
    accum(T, Tpart, Width, Pid0, Sum, Count) when Count > Tpart -> Sum; %base case says: work T / P times.
    accum(T, Tpart, Width, Pid0, Sum, Count) ->

            Temp = get_next(Pid0), %gets a number from the shared counter
            Temp0 = ((Temp - 0.5) * Width),
            Temp1 = math:pow(Temp0, 2.0),
            Temp2 = 1.0 - Temp1,
            Temp3 = math:sqrt(Temp2),
            Temp4 = Temp3 * Width,
            Partial = Sum + Temp4,
            Count2 = Count + 1,
            accum(T, Tpart, Width, Pid0, Partial, Count2). %recursive call



  %Shared Counter. Uses message passing and blocking to allow exclusive       access by one process at a time

   % Main Counter object
    sequence_loop(N) ->
    receive
    {start, G} -> 
    sequence_loop(G);
    {From, get_next} ->
    From ! {self(), N},
    sequence_loop(N + 1)
    end.

  % Retrieve counter and increment.
  get_next(Pid) ->
  Pid ! {self(), get_next},
  receive
 {Pid, N} -> N
  end.
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

- If you just need a unique identifier, use a reference or a list of the worker pids themselves.
- If you need a monotonic *sequence* then the sequence holder should be the one initiating the worker spawns -- multiple processes sending asynch messages provide *zero* guarantees about ordering.

**A bit more depth**

IMO it is better to have the sequence holder be the one to spawn processes than try to force anything approaching a monotonic sequence (especially a sequence with no gaps!) out of async messaging processes.

For example:

```
seq_loop(N, Workers) ->
  receive
    {spawn, {M, F, A}} ->
        Worker = spawn_monitor(M, F, [N | A]),
        seq_loop(N + 1, [Worker | Workers]);
    Down = {'DOWN', _, process, _, _} ->
        NewWorkers = handle_down(Workers, Down),
        seq_loop(N, NewWorkers);
    Other ->
        whatever_else(),
        seq_loop(N, Workers)
  end.
```

You can make this into a system process (manually do `trap_exit`, etc.) or make it a supervisor (*probably the best plan*, but not always -- I mean, who really wants to write yet another `handle_down/2` function unless they have to?) or whatever. But the point is that the way the counter gets incremented *is the same way the newly spawned process gets started* -- unless something crashes, this will effectively be an atomic operation.

The reason I advocate this method is the problem of assumptions. Without realizing it you can very quickly begin to make assumptions about the nature of the sequence -- that it not only gives you a *count* of the number of times the sequence has been accessed, but that the *order* of the integers it has given out bears any relation to the order in which those numbers were used within the system.

If it is just a count you want, then simply keeping track of all the Pids you have spawned by putting them in a list, and then running `length(AllPids)` will give you your answer. If the fact the sequence counts up and goes in order is what matters, then unless you make the sequence-holding process a bottleneck for the entire system by using purely synchronous messaging then you have no way of knowing what process got what number when, because we can't know what order the messages were sent, what order they were received, and what order responses were sent and received *relative to the other workers*.

So, just cutting to the chase and having the process that spawns the workers keep track of the sequences itself eliminates the ordering problem. Keep in mind that the sequence holder could just be telling another process (like a supervisor) to spawn the workers and then pass them their sequence numbers later, so long as you have a K/V record that tells you what Pid belongs to what sequence number.

Comment: Addition is commutative, so Hooray for you! The ordering of the sequence doesn't matter (only completeness does). A typical way to structure something like this would be to have the parent process hold the list, spawn a process per item, receive a result per spawned process, and then perform its final computation on that list. We can continue this in chat; comments are a difficult place to get to the bottom of things: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp

Comment: I ended up figuring this out on my own and modifying the shared counter as the author intended.

Comment: @user2355058 Good to hear! :-) As you work with Erlang a bit more suddenly everything will just make sense all at once, and then you'll wonder how you ever thought of coding some things another way. Its not the best tool for all problems, but for a large subset of programs written today it is.